# storing references of children's of a directory

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, ext2

In a project, the program must store references/identifiers of each child of a directory in its variables(say a stack). i.e the program must not perform pathlookup again for every child once a directory is read.

I am not very sure how to do that. Because if inode numbers are stored, the corresponding file/directory cannot be accessed by the inode right?

Will be gratefull for some pointers

Thanks

Edit: My reasons for "must not perform pathlookup again".....a thread is reading the file system tree in a depth first manner and when it reads a directory...identifiers of its children are saved to follow it in a depth first manner again. Why I save the indentifiers is because a directory that has been read may be moved to another part of the file system by a concurrent thread and the subtree under the moved directory may not be read as that part of the tree has already been traversed.

Comment: The question may sound trivial...but i don't know and hence asking. And its not homework

Answer (score 1):

This smells like homework, except there didn't used to be a way to do this; it is possible now, but only by using the fairly new [`openat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/openat) system call and its friends (see the "see also" list at the bottom of that manpage).  You are correct that you cannot open a file by its inode number; but using the `*at` functions, you can open a file by name *relative to a directory* that you have an open file descriptor (*not* a `DIR*`) for.

Comment: I thought it might be homework because "must not perform pathlookup again" seems like an odd, arbitrary constraint on the problem.  Could you edit into your question an explanation of why you have this constraint?

Comment: So when you say "children", do you mean *everything* in the directory, or do you just mean subdirectories?

Comment: Note that you can use the `dirfd()` function to retrieve the open file descriptor from the `DIR *`.